# PowerPivot de-identifying cell data

Tags: powerpivot, dax

I'm having trouble trying to think of a way through this. I've read Russo/Ferrari books, googled and tried a few things but
I don't think its possible because what I am attempting can't be fulfilled in either row or filter evaluation contexts.

Here's the problem:
I have a dataset which contains sensitive person demographic and non-demographic attributes that by themselves are non-identifying.

For example:
Gender
Ethnicity
Language
Location
Intake type

The dataset itself is sufficiently large enough that if we group by maybe 2 or 3 attributes the individual cell values still contain a big enough value to be non-identifying. Once I start including additional attributes the set is no longer non-identifying.

What I would like to happen is:
a)  that for the 'detail' or lowest level attribute if the sum of values is < 5 then it should show '<5'.
b)  for any level above the lowest I would like the cell value to be the sum of any detail value where that value is >=5 and 5 if its not; prefixed by a '<' sign.

Here is an example of what I would like to see:

```
                  Sum (hidden)  IsFilteredIntakeSource  Required output
City 1                   69             FALSE               <74
    Suburb 1              59            FALSE                <62
      Intake source 1       2           TRUE                   <5
      Intake source 2      57           TRUE                   57
    Suburb 2              10            FALSE                <12
      Intake source 1       7           TRUE                    7
      Intake source 2       3           TRUE                   <5
```

Here's where I'm at, I am currently just using this for the calculated field:

```
IsFilteredIntakeSource:=ISFILTERED(Intake[Intake source])  
De-ident type 2:=if([IsFilteredIntakeSource],if([Intakes]<5,"<5",FORMAT([Intakes], "#")),"De-identified sum")
```

Which gives me this:

```
         Sum (hidden)     IsFilteredIntakeSource     De-ident type 2    
City 1          69                  FALSE           De-identified sum  
Suburb 1            59              FALSE           De-identified sum  
  Intake source 1       2           TRUE            <5  
  Intake source 2      57           TRUE            57  
Suburb 2            10              FALSE           De-identified sum  
  Intake source 1       7           TRUE            7  
  Intake source 2       3           TRUE            <5
```

So I think what I am after is for the last part of the calculation to contain an expression which evaluates to the correct result - maybe CALCULATEDTABLE to give me an interim result and then use that as the basis for the final derivation.

I'm not really after a full working solution (although obviously that would be nice!) on this as I'd prefer to figure it out for myself, more interested
in seeing what other approaches would be viable paths for consideration.

The answer may very well be 'have you considered x' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think that you will need separate measures to handle the values and whether or not they are exact or include an element of de-identification.

The first measure [De-IdentifiedNumber] will calculate all the values at the lowest level, showing those that are less than five as being equal to five.

A second measure (which is the number you actually want to show) will need a pattern along the lines of:

```
[NumberToDisplay]=IF(COUNTROWS(VALUES(Intakes))=1,[De-IdentifiedNumber],SUMX(VALUES(Intakes),[De-IdentifiedNumber]))
```

A third measure [De-IdentifiedFlag] will calculate all the values at the lowest level, showing those that are less than five with a 1, and all others with a 0.

Your required output will just prefix the [NumberToDsiplay] with a "<" if one or more of the rows returns a 1 against the [De-IdentifiedFlag].

Let me know if you want any further guidance, or are happy to work out the rest.

Comment: Well that was just superb! I already had [De-IdentifiedNumber] done so easy follow on that but that VALUES call is just the bees knees. With just 5 minutes fiddling to put in the correct attribute to determine the unique set of values and volia! I admit I would at some point like to improve it so that its not dependent upon a fixed value in the VALUES call - i.e. the 'lowest' slicer can be stated/assigned dynamically but that is for tomorrow at work. Little steps. That's just great, you've sent me on my way, the rest I'd like to figure out for myself, much appreciated.

Comment: "A third measure [De-IdentifiedFlag] will calculate all the values at the lowest level, showing those that are less than five with a 1, and all others with a 0."
It may even be simpler than this, with your solution I think I just need to compare [NumberToDisplay] against [Intakes], if they are different at any level then it must have been as a result of applying the de-identifying algorithm at the lowest level in that branch and therefore I can prefix [NumberToDisplay] just by comparing the two calculated fields.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your post I think that perhaps this link can help you. This web is very usseful DAX Patterns.

http://www.daxpatterns.com/dynamic-segmentation/

Regards

Joana